# How can I simulate a low memory condition in Windows 7

Tags: c#, memory-management, windows-7, garbage-collection

I have an application written in C# that works well, but occasionally in the field gives errors which we believe are due to low memory conditions, or interactions with the garbage collector.

If anyone is interested, it is described here:
[Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Impl.ExpandedQueryExpression' to type 'NHibernate.Linq.NhLinqExpression'](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/649f518c3fbbde53/153d1ec3c9c7c78b?lnk=raot)

I want to try and reproduce this for debugging, but my development machine has too much memory.

I've removed the pagefile so my virtual memory is limited to the 12GBs of physical memory so aside from physically removing ram, does anyone have any suggestions on how to simulate a low memory condition in a development environment?

**EDIT:**
Removed asking about tools which monitor the garbage collector?

Comment: You seem to believe that your *machine* having hardware memory has something to do with the *process* having virtual memory. **That hasn't been true for decades**. Remember, *physical memory* and *virtual memory address space* have pretty much nothing whatsoever to do with each other. The process gets the same amount of virtual memory regardless of how much physical memory you have; more physical memory just makes using virtual memory *faster*. **Do you want to simulate being low on virtual memory address space or low on physical memory**?

Comment: And yes, there are *plenty* of tools that monitor the garbage collector. Get yourself a memory profiler, or watch the perfmon counters.

Comment: @Eric, you are right and I should have been clearer. In attempting to debug this, I've removed the pagefile so my virtual memory is limited to the 12GBs of physical memory.

Comment: What exact reasoning leads you to believe that somehow a lack of memory will lead to an invalid cast exception? I find random issues like these might be more attributable to thread-safety concerns, in this particular case, some code inside the NHibernate library might not be written to behave well under high load scenarios. I certainly would not jump to the conclusion that somehow the available virtual address space or even the machine's amount of physical RAM has anything whatsoever to do with an invalid cast exception.

Comment: @James -- You are right and that is exactly why I am trying to reproduce a low memory condition, to try and test this scenario

Comment: I note that now you are still potentially not simulating what you want to simulate; remember, there is a difference between *not having ability to commit virtual memory to storage because there is no storage, even though there is plenty of address space* and *not having ability to commit virtual memory to storage because there is no address space to map it to.* But a more important question is: why do you believe your problem has anything at all to do with running out of memory? Why should an invalid cast exception lead you to believe that it is a memory problem, rather than a type error?

Comment: @Eric: I don't know for certain, I am following up on one idea that came from the nHibernate forum.  Trying to recreate the conditions that were described in the unable to cast link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a Virtual Machine (VPC, VMWare or Virtual Box) and tune the memory down.

That is more reliable than a bug.

**EDIT**

This suggestion is a way of simulating a PC with less physical memory. As stated in comments and in other answers, if you are looking to tune down virtual memory 'eating away' the heap at the start of the process would be a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can:

[Make Windows pretend it has less memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[Use AppVerifier (only mentioned here for completeness, only works for unmanaged code)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20028)

Or, if you just want to look, just [monitor the collector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985011.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The amount of RAM you have is not relevant on a virtual memory operating system like Windows.  Not having enough only slows down the program.  What matters is the size of the virtual memory address space, 2 gigabytes on a 32-bit operating system.  Set the target platform on your EXE project to x86 if you have a 64-bit operating system.

You can arbitrary increase memory pressure by calling Marshal.AllocHGlobal() at the start of your program.  Allocate a chunk of, say, 500 megabytes.  Not more, that will fail easily.  Grab more by allocating 90 MB chunks.

Comment: you are right and I should have been clearer. In attempting to debug this, I've removed the pagefile so my virtual memory is limited to the 12GBs of physical memory

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but a very cool utility I found at [The Code Project - Memory Allocation Tool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/alloc.aspx)

**Introduction**

Sometimes it is very helpful to test your applications in extreme situations like
low resources, full hard disk, or low memory conditions.

This tool covers just the last - memory.
It allows you to allocate as much memory as might be available.

[image: Memory Allocation Tool]

Comment: Allocates a max of 2GBs, so not helpful for 64 bit machines.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a bug like a tool?

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/521147/large-object-heap-fragmentation-causes-outofmemoryexception

Comment: Because it is not necessarily repeatable and thus unreliable? Because the bug might be fixed tomorrow?

Comment: He asked a solution, this hasn't been fixed yet. This works. He didn't ask a "permanent way to debug".

Answer (score 0):

To monitor the activity of your garbage collector and your processes memory usage you can use windows performance counters.

To fill your RAM why not allocate a rather large array from a c# program?

Comment: Because I think it is caused by the GC and not the memory itself

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple C program to allocate or try to allocate arbitrary amounts of memory on the heap:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MB (1024*1024)
#define DEFAULT_ALLOC ((size_t) (512*MB));

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buffer[2];
    char *chunk;
    char *endp;
    size_t howmuch;

    if ( argc < 2 ) {
        howmuch = DEFAULT_ALLOC;
    }
    else {
        howmuch = strtoul(argv[1], &endp, 10);
        if ( *endp ) {
            fputs("Failed to parse command line argument", stderr);
            howmuch = DEFAULT_ALLOC;
        }
        else {
            howmuch *= MB;
        }
    }

    chunk = calloc(howmuch, 1);

    if ( chunk == NULL ) {
        fputs("Memory allocation error", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    puts("Memory allocated.\nPress ENTER to terminate program");

    fgets(buffer, 2, stdin);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This will consume (virtual) memory of this process, NOT of the .NET application's process

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple program that we use to test low memory conditions on  our linux servers. I have never compiled it on windows, but it should work.

https://github.com/julman99/eatmemory

I Hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Found this utility that is now FreeWare: http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-memalloc/